# Object position in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of `Object`s. Now my question is how I can find out what position the object is in from within it?

My object array

```
public myObject[] objects = new myObject[10];
```

The constructor of myObject

```
public myObject(){
    int objectID = 0; //Here should be the code to find the position in the array
}
```

Comment: Try something first, then we will help you.

Comment: How could the object be in an array if it's not even constructed yet? Show us real code. Your code doesn't make much sense as is. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class MyObject should have a method which gets the array and returns the idx

```
class MyObject {
   public int findIdx(MyObject[] myObjects) {
        if (myObjects != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= myObjects.length; i++) {
                if (myObjects[i].equals(this)) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop over your array to find the position of your object, using whatever equality check you require.

EDIT:
As everyone seems to be concerned over `.equals` vs `==` I've changed the routine to perform either. If you're checking for reference equality, use `findValue(ary, obj, true)`, otherwise use `findValue(ary, obj, false)`

This will not find null values. I suggest throwing an exception here if `myObject` is null, but I will leave that decision to you.

```
public int findValue(Object[] objects, Object myObject, boolean equalityCheck){
    for(int i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
        if(equalityCheck){
            if(objects[i] == myObject){
                return i;
            }
        }else{
            if(objects[i]!=null && myObject!=null && objects[i].equals(myObject)){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This code is performing a linear search to find the position of the object.  Its not very efficient on larger arrays. As you seem to be a beginner I'm not going to dive into how to optimize this, but just be aware.

Comment: -1 `objects == myObject` will **never** work in this case (but looks that upvoters don't even understand the problem with this approach).

Comment: Syntax error, fixed. Small mistake.

Comment: I'm missing a `break` when you found your object. Why wasting time?

Comment: @MarounMaroun 1st: we must not fix answerers code, just help with format. 2nd: using `==` is a **huge** mistake here.

Comment: I disagree. Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison `==` compares references, so in the first moment you use `new ...` you have a totally new reference. Now with your edit, it's not easy to see if you're indeed passing an existent element of the array to this method. When comparing object references, you should use `equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison As Luiggi mentioned, you should replace `==` with `.equals` in your code. `==` will **always** yields false in this case.

Comment: By your last edit, looks like you really need to learn Java...

Comment: Ah my mistake you are both correct. The code has changed many times since your comments however, I hope you understand my confusion. No need for personal attacks, they show insecurity on your part.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison your code show insecurity about your knowledge...

Comment: The method I wrote above is used in a framework I work with daily. :) @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Thanks for noticing me, I won't use that framework :)

Comment: Your loss. Couldn't help but notice. Your blather is incessant.

Comment: Instead of writing such bad code for equality check, use something from a real framework like [`ObjectUtils#equals`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/alibaba/citrus/tool/antx-autoexpand/1.0.10/antx-autoexpand-1.0.10-sources.jar!/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.java?format=ok) (check that code, that's a real world framework).

Comment: uh huh, looks like something a first year student would learn. Perfect for you! http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Game/libgdx/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.java.htm